# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack - polyval function

Tags: python

My code looks like this (except i changed the numbers as originally they referred to variables):

```
x = array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = array([1,2,3,4,5])
scatter(qnkt,Is)
p1 = polyfit(x, y, 1)
y,delta = polyval(p1,x)
graph1 = poly1d(p1)
ys = graph1(qnkt)
plot(x, ys)
```

I get an error:

```
 y,delta = polyval(p1,qnkt)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Can anyone explain why this is? I am trying to use polyval to calculate the error (standard deviation).

Answer (score 2):

In Python, when doing unpacking of arguments or other collections - the number of names on the left side must match the number of items on the right. If there is an imbalance on the *right*, you will get this exception.

Here is an example:

```
>>> a,b = (1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

If you have an imbalance on the left, you get a different exception:

```
>>> a,b = (1,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Now we know what is happening to your line. The `polyval` method is returning an object that has more than 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get `polyval` function from? It's not part of the [standard library](http://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=polyval). You seem to be passing an incorrect number of arguments to it.

Your code also doesn't correspond to the line of code the error is referring to. Given that you explain none of the variables in your code it is extremely hard to even suggest what is correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> polyval(p1,x)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

as you can see, *numpy.polyval* returns only one array, which I believe is *y*, and there is no *delta*, which you might expect if you're porting matlab code.

Comment: Could you say... anything... aside from the code paste, to help people understand?

Comment: @radpin my reply was a try to demonstrate obvious reason of fail- result of function call is just different from expected. You're right, it's not obvious for those people who might not know python well enough. I've updated my reply, hope this would help you and further people who face same problem.